# Behavior of Async logger in log4j2

Tags: java, xml, asynchronous, logging, log4j2

My log4j2.xml contains both sync and async loggers. However, when I use the async loggers I could only get the first (out of 5) log.debug statement to be printed.

Update 3/28 --
If I introduce a `Thread.sleep(1)` before the log.debug calls..  then I am able to get all the debug messages logged via `Async logger --> Rewrite Appender --> Rolling File Appender` But not sure how to achieve this without that sleep statement..

```
<Configuration status="WARN" packages="com.loggy.test">
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>

    <!--  Custom Appender Approach below -->
    <Stub name="myapp" fileName="/Users/loggy/logs/myapp.log"
                 filePattern="logs/myapp-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.log.gz">
         <RegexFilter regex=".* special_log .*" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
        <PatternLayout>
                    <pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</pattern>
          </PatternLayout>
          <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
    </Stub>
    <!--  Custom Appender Approach above ends here -->

    <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="/Users/loggy/logs/roll_file_app.log"
                 filePattern="logs/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.log.gz">
           <PatternLayout>
                    <pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</pattern>
          </PatternLayout>
          <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
    </RollingFile>


    <Rewrite name="Rewrite" ignoreExceptions = "false">
        <CookieAppenderPolicy cookieNeeded="true">
        </CookieAppenderPolicy>
        <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
    </Rewrite>
  </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <AsyncLogger name="com.loggy.test" level="debug" includeLocation="true">
            <AppenderRef ref="Rewrite" />
        </AsyncLogger>  
    <Root level="trace">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>




package com.loggy.test;

public class TestJ {
    @Inject
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final Logger log4j = LogManager.getLogger(TestJ.class
                .getName());


        log4j.trace(" special_log Trace");

/* When Async logger is used, Only this line below gets printed to the Rewrite Appender and hence to the Rolling File appender */

        log4j.debug(" special_log debug published!");

    log4j.info(" special_log test info");


    log4j.debug(" sd_log test info");

   /* Following lines NEVER gets published to the rolling file appender or to the Rewrite Appender */

    log4j.debug(" special_log debug 2");

    log4j.debug(" special_log debug 3");

    log4j.debug(" special_log debug 4");

    log4j.debug(" special_log debug 5");

}
```

However, if I include the `<AppenderRef ref="Rewrite" />` outside the `<AsyncLogger>` then I get all the lines published.

Any thoughts as to what should be changed with the log4j2.xml so that I get all the appropriate lines when I use the AsyncLogger?

I also noticed that inside log4j2 package the`AsyncLoggerConfig.java` class the code never gets to the `super.callAppenders(event);`.

I am assuming that the `super.callAppenders(event)` has to work for the referenced appenders to be called? How can I make this line be executed via the log4j2.xml?

```
/**  AsyncLoggerConfig.java
 * Passes on the event to a separate thread that will call
 * {@link #asyncCallAppenders(LogEvent)}.
 */
@Override
protected void callAppenders(final LogEvent event) {
    // populate lazily initialized fields
    event.getSource();

event.getThreadName();

// pass on the event to a separate thread
if (!helper.callAppendersFromAnotherThread(event)) {
    super.callAppenders(event);
}
}
```

---

Comment: Did you disable the `shutdownHook`?

Comment: thanks @wangyuntao . Unfortunately, now none of the lines get logged .. after adding the shutdownHook=disable to the log4j2.xml config file ..     `<Configuration status="WARN" packages="com.loggy.test" shutdownHook="disable">` .

Comment: I actually just mean you should not disable it.

Comment: If it is disabled and you don't shut it down explicitly, some logs may not be flushed to the file when your app is terminated.

Comment: yes @wangyuntao ... if i enabled the shutdownhook then I only get the first message and none of the other messages. This is the same issue that I originally described. However, Sync logger works great and I get all the log messages as intended..

Comment: Which version of Log4j2 are you using? Some Thread related issues were fixed recently.

Comment: Thanks for the input @RemkoPopma . I am using log4j-core-2.0-rc1.jar, log4j-api-2.0-rc1.jar, disruptor-3.3.6.jar. I also have log4j-1.2-api-2.0-rc1.jar in the path. but I am not using this one in code.

Comment: Wow that is an old version! Please upgrade to Log4j 2.8.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem has been resolved in later versions of Log4j. The solution is to upgrade from version 2.0-rc1 to the latest version (2.8.1 as of this writing).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is due to application's shutdown event shutting down the async log threads that haven't finished writing. Same issue as described here - [shutdown hook called too early] https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-658.